# BaseStatefulBolt (Storm Core) vs StateFactory (Storm Trident)

Tags: apache-storm, trident

i am confused about using storm. I am going to measure status of data source using its streamed data. Status will be calculated with combine of some fields, and these field can be achieved different time interval. That's why i need to save fields to measure status of data source.

Can i use BaseStatefulBolt? Or the only solution is trident for this cenario?

What is the difference btw them. Because there is a statefactory inside trident too.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I think the difference is trident is higher level than BaseStatefulBol, it has some options for counting like group by,persistentAggregate,aggregate .

I have used trident for counting total view per user. If we only care about current total count, I think we can use trident by using MemoryMapState.Factory() and class implement action for counting or summing.

In your case you need to managing status of some current fields , I think implement BaseStatefulBolt is a good choice, it has KeyValueState for save current state.